# Comparing Strings - Converting from SQL on C# to stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I currently trying to convert sql queries into stored procedures but I have difficulty  converting when it comes to comparing of strings.

Below is the SQL code on my C# application:

```
String Query = @"select label
, marking
from
(
select count(equipment) as num_equipments
from CS_PM_EQUI_INFO
where " + Perspective + " = '" + Workcenter + @"'
)
```

Below is what I tried to convert to stored procedures:

```
begin  
    stmt := '
    select label
    , marking
          from
    ( 
    select count(equipment) as num_equipments         
    from CS_PM_EQUI_INFO         
    where '|| perspective ||' = '||' Workcenter '||'
    )
```

Am I doing it correctly? I am trying to compare perspective and workcenter, both are string parameters. Example: Workcenter value is ABC, where perspective = 'ABC'.

Please kindly help me with this as the results returned are not the desired one.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your db server (sql-server/mysql/oracle)? Subqueries are not returning the columns you trying to get from the main query. Why don't you create stored procedures in the db server itself and pass parameters from your code?

Comment: I'm not so sure if a SELECT from columns "marking" and "label" will actually work when there is only a column "num_equipments".

Comment: Hi Kaf, im using oracle right now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your existing code: the value for the variable `Workcenter` is embedded in the SQL statement, whereas you should be using bind variables. Also `Perspective` contains the name of a column and you should make sure that it contains no SQL injection attempt (the `dbms_assert` package is good for this).

Secondly, I'm not sure how your existing query is working when you're selecting columns in the outer query not present in the subquery.

As to an actual solution, in an Oracle stored procedure you can do something like the following:

```
function my_func(my_column in varchar2, my_value in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  q varchar2(1000);
  return_value varchar2(1000);
begin
  q := 'select other_column from my_table where ' || my_column || ' = :my_value';

  execute immediate q into return_value using my_value;

  return return_value;
end my_func;
```

If `my_column` can be specified by an end user (ie, not from constants in code) then you should use `dbms_assert.simple_sql_name` to assert that the string is safe to use.